# Maven automatically adds LICENSE into .jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

How can I change/remove license in my .jar that maven has put in there?

When I change .jar to .zip and i will enter this zip file there is META-INF folder where is license file.

As I read it is Apache License and I need GPLv3. How can I change it?

It is this github project http://github.com/magx2/StrangeCtrl

I forked it from guy who licensed his code on GPLv3

Comment: You want to change it in the build process ? If not with 7-zip you can open the jar, remove and add your lic file.

Comment: BTW, you can`t change product licensed as Apache to GPLv3

Comment: If this is GPLv3, can you post link to source code or `pom.xml`?

Comment: It is this github project https://github.com/magx2/StrangeCtrl I forked it from guy who licensed his code on GPLv3

Comment: I builded **strangectrl-1.1-alpha.jar** with maven and there is no license inside.

Comment: Weird. See jars that are in repo. In these jars is META-INf/license

Comment: Give me a link to the repo

Comment: http://github.com/magx2/StrangeCtrl also it's in main post

Comment: Maven does not add such thing in build.

Answer (score 0):

Find this license in project structure and replace with GPLv3.

Probably this is [License Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/) used for this. If this is true, reconfigure this plugin in `pom.xml`.

Comment: There is no file with this licence in project structure. Maven took it from nowhere.

Comment: @MAGx2 Search `pom.xml` for word *license*, any results? Can you post here `pom.xml`?